# cant receive payload from post method in expressJS

Tags: javascript, express

hello im using express for server everything is working find but i am not receiving my data from post method.Iam using body-parser too

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post("/signup", (req,res)=>{
    var data = req.body
    res.send(req.body)
})
```

Comment: can you log on what you are getting on req.body? Also, are you sending data in your body while posting

Comment: yes i am giving data in body, and it shows an empty object

Comment: What format is the payload in?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a 100% working code. If it doesn’t work, then tell me how do you make a POST request?

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  var data = req.body
  console.log(data)
  res.send(req.body)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Front-end:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signup', {
  firstName: 'Fred',
  lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: still not working :( . Iam using postman get,put all method is working fine here is my data { "username":"ammar","pass":"123"}

Comment: Try it like this:

Postman:
- POST
- Body = raw = { test: "123" }

Comment: no no iam trying to say that all other method are working fine except post

Comment: Add Headers:
Key: Content-Type
Value: application/json

Comment: {test : "123"} it works!! but iam receiving my data like this {"{\ntest : \"123\",\n}":""}

Comment: **Headers: Key: Content-Type Value: application/json** it works. please can you tell me what should i do if iam sending my data from frontend to prevent that problem

Comment: What are you using at the frontend? jquery/axios/etc.?

Comment: iam using react and axios

Comment: Thank you so much :)